# How can i add a animation on the button' imageview when the button' state changed in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I have a button here, and set two different images for two different state:

```
button.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
button.setImage(image2, for: .selected)
```

now i want to add an animation on the button's imageview when the button' state changed, so how can i make it? if anyone can help me ,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
    button.setIMage(image1, for: .normal)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        button.setImage(image2, for: .selected)
    }
```